# Using join incorrectly?

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I can't seem to get results with my joins. I'm wondering if I'm joining these tables wrong or I'm doing something else wrong. I've looked over the tables and it seems right.

```
USE AdventureWorks2016;

SELECT 
    C.CustomerID, P.FirstName, P.LastName, A.City, S.StateProvinceCode
FROM 
    Sales.Customer AS C 
JOIN 
    Person.BusinessEntityContact AS BC ON BC.PersonID = C.PersonID 
JOIN 
    Person.Person AS P ON P.BusinessEntityID = BC.BusinessEntityID
JOIN 
    Person.BusinessEntityAddress AS BA ON BA.BusinessEntityID = BC.BusinessEntityID
JOIN 
    Person.Address AS A ON A.AddressID = BA.AddressID
JOIN 
    Person.StateProvince AS S ON S.StateProvinceID = A.StateProvinceID
```

Comment: Are you missing somthing here? **JOIN Person.Person AS P ON P.BusinessEntityID = BC.** <--

Comment: What is the actual problem? There is no explanation of your issue. What are solving here?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid the issue I'm having is that when I execute the query it returns nothing at all and it should.

Comment: You just need to take table joins out one by one until you identify which table join is stopping the records. Can you edit your query and put what you're actually using? The `BC.` in the query you posted will throw an error

Comment: Why would BC. throw an error? @Nick.McDermaid

Comment: `Person.Person AS P ON P.BusinessEntityID = BC.` is not valid syntax. Please look at your actual posted question.

Comment: I must've fat fingered entering the code. It wasn't in my code that I copied from.

Comment: There are a number of suggestions here - why don't you start trying some of them.

Comment: why dont you use a left join to test null values so you can get why there is no result

Comment: or add your tables to your query for join, one by one. first  C join BC then run if u can see results then join P and so on...

Comment: Can you get results "by hand"? Start with some known customers, inspect the foreign keys, try and find the corresponding records in the other tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to select customers that are their own business contact, and there are no such customers. I suggest to remove the *BusinessEntityContact* table from the query and try this instead:

```
SELECT C.CustomerID, P.FirstName, P.LastName, A.City, S.StateProvinceCode
FROM Sales.Customer AS C 
  JOIN Person.Person AS P ON C.PersonID = P.BusinessEntityID 
    JOIN Person.BusinessEntityAddress AS BA ON P.BusinessEntityID = BA.BusinessEntityID 
      JOIN Person.Address AS A ON BA.AddressID = A.AddressID 
        JOIN Person.StateProvince AS S ON A.StateProvinceID = S.StateProvinceID
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have had a mistake in joining Person table to BusinessEntityContact.
Based on the query you provided, I think you should join these tables based on PersonId field.

```
SELECT C.CustomerID, P.FirstName, P.LastName, A.City, S.StateProvinceCode
FROM Sales.Customer AS C JOIN Person.BusinessEntityContact AS BC ON 
BC.PersonID = C.PersonID 
JOIN Person.Person AS P ON P.PersonID = BC.PersonID 
JOIN Person.BusinessEntityAddress AS BA ON BA.BusinessEntityID = 
BC.BusinessEntityID
JOIN Person.Address AS A ON A.AddressID = BA.AddressID
JOIN Person.StateProvince AS S ON S.StateProvinceID = A.StateProvinceID
```

Comment: Can you please also add a sentence or two **explaining** what you've done and how that is supposed to solve the issue the OP is having ?? Just dumping a pile of code without any explanation isn't really very helpful....

Comment: Unfortunately there is no P.PersonID. The only key in the Person.Person table is the BuesinessEntityID column. @AminMozhgani

Comment: @icodin Change all of your inner join into left outer join and find witch table hasn't related record

Comment: @AminMozhgani so you when I change all my joins to left outer joins all the columns except the customerID column shows up null.

Comment: @icodin It means that there is not any related data in your tables so it can't link them by join clause